# Normalization of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

This is a point in an exercise given during my Commutative Algebra course. Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field with characteristic different from $2$. Let $R=\frac{k[x,y]}{(y^{2}-f(x))}$, where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of odd degree. I showed that $R$ is a domain of dimension $1$ and that the localization $R_{m}$ is normal except for maximal ideals of the kind $(x-a,y)$ with $a$ multiple root of $f$. My question is how to compute the normalization of $R$. I think that the right way is to invert, by localizing, all factors of $f(x)$ of the kind $(x-a)^l$ with $l>1$, but I don't know concretely how to proceed or how to show that it's the right way.

Comment: Dear Simone, Inverting these factors will not give the normalization.  The map from $R$ to its normalization will be an integral (indeed, finite) map, whereas the map from $R$ to a localization $R_a$ will never be integral if $R$ is a domain and $a$ is a non-unit.  Regards,

Comment: I think could be useful to observe that $R$ is integrally closed iff $f(x)$ has no multiple factors. If $f(x)$ isn't squarefree I think it's integral closure is $k[t]$, but I'm not sure.